# Accessing data from collection

Tags: c#

I have a data collection returning from a custom function that I can enumerate though but I can't get just a single item (i don't understand syntax):

```
foreach (var document in currentDoc)
{
    // This works
    item = document["MenuItemTeaserImage"].ToString();
}

//Doesn't work
string itemSingle = currentDoc[0]["MenuItemTeaserImage"].ToString()
```

If I can enumerate through something is there a standard way I can access the data in a single instance?

Comment: it is depending on what the type of `currentDoc` is. If it is a `IEnumerable<Document>` then no you can't, if it is something else then maybe.

Comment: What's the type of currentDoc?

Comment: `IList` is the interface that defines the indexer. Possibly as others noted `currentDoc` is an IEnumerable<T>. You can try calling `ToList()` on `currentDoc` and try like that.

Comment: Also, if you only care about getting `[0]` then `currentDoc.First()["MenuItemTeaserImage"].ToString()` would work.

Comment: If currentDoc is a List or Array then you can index it using currentDoc[0] otherwise you could get a single item using currentDoc.First() if it at least implements IEnumerable<T>

Comment: oh, I thought it was a standard thing. The type is "CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentQuery" from kentico https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/9_0/api/html/T_CMS_DocumentEngine_DocumentQuery.htm

Comment: You only get IEnumerable<T> with that one from the looks of it. So only stuff like .First(), or .Skip(x).First() for the x+1th item will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with Linq using [Enumerable.First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var itemSingle = currentDoc.First()["MenuItemTeaserImage"].ToString();
```

The likely reason the for loop works is that your `currentDoc` is an `IEnumerable`, which supports enumeration but not indexed access.

If you want to access other elements than the first you can turn `currentDoc` into an array `currentDoc.ToArray()` or into a list `currentDoc.ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

```
string itemSingle = currentDoc.Single()["MenuItemTeaserImage"].ToString();
```

This will work if there is exactly 1 item in currentDoc, it will throw an exception if there are 0 or 2+ items.

If you have 0 or 1 items, then you can use currentDoc.SingleOrDefault() instead, you will get back a null if currentDoc is empty.

If you have more than 1 item, then you can use currentDoc.First() or currentDoc.FirstOrDefault() but in that case you might want to think about why you have multiple items in your collection and which one is the 'correct' one to use.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it is important to denote, that `Single` or `First` will throw an exception if an item isn't found in your collection.  I would lean towards `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault`. The second item, which I believe is being misconstrued, you want to edit a single item in your collection.  Except you believe you need to grab the initial item, before you edit.

You can do this several approaches:

```
var example = collection.ElementAt(0);
if(example != null)
     collection[example].Property = value;


collection.FirstOrDefault().Property = value;
collection.SingleOrDefault().Property = value;
```

If you would simply like the first item in the collection:

```
var example = collection.ElementAt(0) as string;
var example = collection.FirstOrDefault() as string;
var example = collection.SingleOrDefault() as string;
```

Those are several approaches, be careful with `ToString`, if the value doesn't exist it will throw an exception.